# How do I pass a managedObjectContext to the tablecontroller in my second tab?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have two tabs. Tab 1 and Tab2.

In tab2 I have a table view controller displaying a table. The table view controller is inside a navigationcontroller. I am using storyboard.

I need to pass my managedObjectContext to the second tab so that I can display the data in the table.

This is what I have so far but it seems quite rigid. How do I pass the context without getting it from the delegate? So far I have this but if I understand correctly, I need to pass the context to svc from fcv and not directly in the delegate.

```
FirstViewController *fvc = (FirstViewController *)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

SecondViewController *svc = (SecondViewController *)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

fvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
svc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay

expose the pertinent core data objects in your app delegate

```
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

In both your FirstViewController and SecondViewController you then access the moc (and the other stuff if you need to) as above (Marko's answer) except mod is shown....

```
[(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: thanks but apparently this is not the "good way" of doing this. This is why im trying to pass it from the first view controller

Comment: but it makes sense to me to have the context somewhere accessible by all instead of passing it around

Answer (score 1):

Try the other way round: If the managedObjectController is maintained in the app delegate, you can get it from anywhere in your app with the following call (replace "MyAppDelegate" with whatever your delegate is called):

```
[(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectController];
```

Comment: This is a bad idea as it makes testing extremely hard and makes your design much more rigid

Comment: This is fine for an app that only refers to one managed object context. What alternative would you suggest?

Comment: I always find the opposite, i.e. all your core data objects are in one place. I can see the rigidity argument though I would counter that the vast majority of apps are happy with just a single moc throughout the runcycle of the app. How does it make testing hard?

Comment: It makes it harder to have a consistant starting point for your unit tests to run from. Dependancy inversion is one of the SOLID design principles for decoupling your code, which you should take a look at. `vast majority of apps are happy...` what if you decided that at some point one of your objects needed to run in a background thread now you need to redesign because of this rigidness.

Comment: I agree with the (unit) testing argument, since you can't easily pass for example an in-memory context for testing to the function. However, unless you deal with multiple contexts and don't do TDD, i think that this is still a valid approach for a basic app. If, however, you deal with multiple contexts, you open a totally different can of worms. I wouldn't recommend it if you can't find a better solution for this (relatively easy) questions yourself.

Comment: Yup it probably makes no difference on a small project but I would argue that it takes pretty much the same amount of code/effort to do either way, but I think I like the idea of making my app more extendable in the future over convenience of sticking everything in a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, I see the background thread argument and I've actually come up against a scenario were I needed to use a separate moc in a background thread to do work but still, I'm not sure Dependancy Inversion is a valid stance, we're talking about two view controllers which [okay - 'probably'] want to do the same thing on the same data layer, i.e. make a change in one vc and you want to see it reflected in the next vc and not necessarily before saving the context. I'm going to stick with my answer but caveat for 'simple implementations' and go away and read up on Dependancy Inversion! :-D

Comment: Using app delegate to hold a pointer to the moc doesn't mean all of the logic for managing the moc has to be inside the app delegate. It would be better to put that logic into a separate "data" object that is only concerned with your moc. Then you have more options for referencing the moc indirectly through this data object, as well as all other logic associated with the moc, including sharing data with other objects. You then have nothing but an abstract reference to the data object, and the concrete implementation details can remain outside of the methods that get you access to the moc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. If you want to make it a little easier on yourself you could make sure you are consistant with your naming (which you currently are) and use something like

```
for (id controller in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    if ([controller respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)]) {
        [controller performSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:) withObject:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
}
```

This would allow you to add/remove and reorder the tabs without things breaking on you. This is taking advantage of convention over configuration.

Comment: Interesting. So this will loop through all the different tabs and set the managedobjectcontext if it exists.. but since the tab that interests me is under a navigation controller and under a tabcontroller, I don't think this loop will access it.

Comment: Everything is created using storyboards and ios 5 sdk xcode 4.2

Comment: Ah sorry I've not got onto that yet got some legacy projects holding me back :(

Comment: Each navigation controller will have a `topViewController` property that should point to your initial non-controller-of-controllers scene.